# How to use any Hindi Font in Itext7?

Tags: c#, fonts, itext7, truetype

I am using iText 7.net to create a pdf in Hindi or english based on user language selection input but I can't figure out any way to convert my selected Hindi .ttf font files to itext Pdffonts. It works fine in English with standard Itext Fonts.

This is my code:

```
    PdfFontFactory.Register(HindiFont1.ToString(), "HindiFont1");

    //Error at this line: Font Not Recognized
    PdfFont myHindiFont1 = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont("HindiFont1", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
    //Create Writer
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(path);

    //Create Pdf Document Object
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdf, size);
    PdfPage page1 = pdf.AddNewPage();
     PdfCanvas canvas3 = new PdfCanvas(page3);
    Rectangle pageSize3 = page3.GetPageSize();

    //String in Title9 Paragraph is a translation of English Phrase
     iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph Title9 = new iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph("ew[;kad fo'kslrk;sa%");

    Title9.SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER);
   // Title9.SetFont(myHindiFont1);

     document.Close();
```

The code gives error while saving pdf second line at the top. variable HindiFont1 holds the Hindi Font .ttf file.

String in Title9 Paragraph is a translation of English Phrase.

Can anyone help in using my hindi fonts? I have 4-5 fonts I want to use.

Comment: For Hindi support you should generally look into the [iText 7 pdfCalligraph add-on](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfcalligraph). Concerning your specific question, though: *"The code gives error while saving pdf second line at the top"* - Which error exactly? And can you share enough data (in particular the font in question) to allow reproducing the issue?

Comment: Error is font.is.not.recognized and font that I am trying to use is LeoPalmHindi15K710. How can I share the font file with you? I dont see any attach files button here. Can I share font file over google drive?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16BTq3E0V8x0OoJFw5mW_4XmTa0jw2LmZ/view?usp=sharing  This link will let you download the font file from my drive.

Comment: Itext PdfCalligraph is a commercial tool? Do I need to purchase it or can I download its free library?

Comment: It is commercial, you need a license. You can request a free trial, though.

Comment: With your font, though, I doubt that the pdfCalligraph add-on would help you as it assigns the Hindi glyphs to Latin characters. For pdfCalligraph to be helpful, it needs to know that given glyphs are e.g. Hindi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to retrieve a previously registered font use the `PdfFontFactory` method `CreateRegisteredFont` instead of `CreateFont`. Thus, replace

```
PdfFont myHindiFont1 = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont("HindiFont1", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
```

by

```
PdfFont myHindiFont1 = PdfFontFactory.CreateRegisteredFont("HindiFont1", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
```

Then, if you want to add text to a paragraph to be drawn in a specific font, first set the font, then add the text. Thus, instead of

```
iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph Title9 = new iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph("ew[;kad fo'kslrk;sa%");
Title9.SetFont(myHindiFont1);
```

do

```
iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph Title9 = new iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph().SetFont(myHindiFont1).Add("ew[;kad fo'kslrk;sa%");
```

Alternatively you can set that font as document default font:

```
Document document = new Document(pdf, size);
document.SetFont(myHindiFont1);

iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph Title9 = new iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph("ew[;kad fo'kslrk;sa%");
```

And finally, add your new paragraph to some entity, e.g.

```
document.Add(Title9);
```

The result:

[image]

---

Here the final code I used to successfully render the above screen shot:

```
String HindiFont1 = @"LEOPALMHINDI15K710.TTF";
PageSize size = PageSize.A4;

PdfFontFactory.Register(HindiFont1, "HindiFont1");

//Error at this line: Font Not Recognized
PdfFont myHindiFont1 = PdfFontFactory.CreateRegisteredFont("HindiFont1", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
//Create Writer
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(@"UseLeopalmhindi15K710LikeDivyanshuAgarwalImproved.pdf");

//Create Pdf Document Object
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdf, size);
//document.SetFont(myHindiFont1);
//String in Title9 Paragraph is a translation of English Phrase
//iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph Title9 = new iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph("ew[;kad fo'kslrk;sa%");
iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph Title9 = new iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph().SetFont(myHindiFont1).Add("ew[;kad fo'kslrk;sa%");

Title9.SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER);

document.Add(Title9);

document.Close();
```

Comment: I am gonna give it a try right now. Finger's Crossed.

Comment: okay I dont know how you got it to work but throws this error on my end..

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
iText.Layout.Renderer.TextRenderer.ConvertToGlyphLine (System.String text) (at <0b6ebc25fe5349debfa3cd4517a89bd7>:0)
iText.Layout.Renderer.TextRenderer.ConvertWaitingStringToGlyphLine () (at <0b6ebc25fe5349debfa3cd4517a89bd7>:0)
iText.Layout.Renderer.TextRenderer.ApplyOtf () (at <0b6ebc25fe5349debfa3cd4517a89bd7>:0)

Comment: iText.Layout.Renderer.LineRenderer.Layout (iText.Layout.Layout.LayoutContext layoutContext) (at <0b6ebc25fe5349debfa3cd4517a89bd7>:0)
iText.Layout.Renderer.ParagraphRenderer.Layout (iText.Layout.Layout.LayoutContext layoutContext) (at <0b6ebc25fe5349debfa3cd4517a89bd7>:0)
iText.Layout.Renderer.RootRenderer.AddChild (iText.Layout.Renderer.IRenderer renderer) (at <0b6ebc25fe5349debfa3cd4517a89bd7>:0)
iText.Layout.RootElement`1[T].Add[T2] (iText.Layout.Element.BlockElement`1[T] element) (at <0b6ebc25fe5349debfa3cd4517a89bd7>:0)

Comment: iText.Layout.Document.Add[T] (iText.Layout.Element.BlockElement`1[T] element) (at <0b6ebc25fe5349debfa3cd4517a89bd7>:0)
Panel.HindiPdf () (at Assets/Scripts/Panel.cs:7123)
Panel+<ShowSaveDialogCoroutine>d__112.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/Panel.cs:6791)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)

Comment: The whole three comments are one single error I get.

Comment: I added the complete code of my test case. Please try that. If it does not work, something weird is going on. If (as I expect) it works, though, change it step by step to match your code. Obviously you will have to use a proper path to the font file in `HindiFont1`.

Comment: Thanks a Lot man, you are great. You always come up with best solutions. It worked. Only mistake I was doing is using an variable to get Font Reference as string. So nothing was being passed in RegisterFonts until I created a path string to the Font File and it Works Wonders. Thanks

Comment: it is not working with "छोटी इ की मात्रा वाले शब्द"